# Jquery scrollTop does break the layout, while scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, scrolltop

I've got a problem with the jQuery scrollTop function. Everytime, when somebody clicks on my "back-to-top" button the layout will crash, while the animation is running. There is now special code around it, just a button.scrollTop(0);

The styling of the layout is a border-box layout.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you add your code to JS fiddle or PHP fiddle so that we can see?

Answer (score 0):

Just to test whether the function itself is not causing the problem try to put an empty div on the very top of your body markup

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"></div>
...
...
<button id="test-button">Scroll to top</button>
</body>
```

and then in a JS file try to do this

```
var topButton = document.getElementById("test-button");
var test = document.getElementById("test");
topButton.onclick(function(){
     test.get(0).scrollIntoView();
});
```

This is not smooth scroll, but if this works then the rest of your HTML markup is probably fine.

Comment: Sorry I didn't test it, because I've figured out a working solution: read below

Answer (score 0):

As for what I can see from your explanation is that you want to scroll to the top after a button click. But you can not add the scrollTop directly to the button.

I would expect you use something like:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('html').scrollTop(0);
})
```

Would that solve your problem?

Comment: this is the way I've done it before. And it failed. But read below for the correct working fix ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is my working solution here:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop': '0px'
    });
}, 300);
```

The problem was becaused by the instant scroll to top.

Thanks all for the help!